# Chrome PDF preview not showing up in embed container

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

I'm showing pdfs in an `embed` by using

`<embed id="pdfPrev" src="foo.pdf">`

An example of how this is rendered in Chrom is shown below

[image]

It's in a "container" and shows a preview and has buttons download, zoom, rotate, print, etc..

However, an end user is seeing something different

[image]

The first thing I thought was that they had some custom Chrome extension for rendering PDFs. This was not the case.

Also, we have the same exact versions of Chrome. Opening up in a private window didn't resolve it either.

Edit: Here's the css I'm using for the actual embed.

```
#pdfPrev{
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Gray border */
  border-radius: 4px;  /* Rounded border */
  padding: 5px; /* Some padding */
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto; /* Will not center vertically and won't work in IE6/7. */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Add a hover effect (blue shadow) */
#pdfPrev:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It was due to a Chrome setting to automatically download PDF files. Disabling this made it work. Setting was hard to find.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you didn't give much info about your situation
But can you force the height and width !

something like this :

```
<embed src="foo.pdf" width="400px" height="1000px" />
```

Comment: Hi! I just added the styling I'm using for the `embed` tag. You can see that there's a set height and width

Comment: With the height and width I have in my css above, the PDF buttons still always show on my computer. Even if I resize my window or drag the window from my external monitor to my actual laptop screen.